# Javascript crop and scale image to be 300 pixel

Tags: javascript, image, scale, crop

I want to know how we can scale and crop an image in Javascript. I want to scale it down to 300x300px and crop it a little.
Do you have any suggestions ? I have the following code :

```
function cropImage(imagePath, newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight) {
//create an image object from the path
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,"+imagePath;
    
//alert(img.width);
//alert(img.height);
//initialize the canvas object
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



    //set the canvas size to the new width and height
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
     
    //draw the image
    
        ctx.drawImage(img, newX, 75, 300, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    variables.imageCrop = canvas.toDataURL();}
```

Thank you !

Comment: the `imagePath ` is an url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

And learn more about [`.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

```js
function cropImage(imagePath, leftRight, topBottom, newWidth, newHeight) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = imagePath;

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  
  //Set your canvas size as your choice
  //here i just scaled by 10 with original dimension
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth*10;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight*10;
    
    const cropLeft = leftRight[0];
    const cropRight = img.naturalWidth - leftRight[0] - leftRight[1];
    
    const cropTop = topBottom[0];
    const cropBottom = img.naturalHeight - topBottom[0] - topBottom[1];
    ctx.drawImage(
    img, 
    cropLeft,cropTop,
    cropRight, cropBottom,
    0,0, //here you can control placement of cropped image from left and top, by default it stays in 0,0 meaning the top left corner of the canvas
    newWidth,newHeight //new width and height of cropped image
    );
  });
}

//Size of this image is 100x100 px
const img = "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/09f/fff";

//here [10,10] meaning crop 10px from left and 10px from right
//here [20,20] meaning crop 20px from top and 20px from bottom
cropImage(img,[10,10],[20,20], 100, 100);
```

Comment: The URL is 100 % correct don't bother with it, the picture is showing well. My problem is that I want to crop the image, for example I want to remove 50px left and right, I can't do it with that could I add another drawImage?

Comment: @AdamHarmand Now I understand what you want to achieve, I have refactored the codes as per your requirements and also added some comments.