How to Achieve Square Camera View with SDK 51?
I recently upgraded to SDK 51 and noticed that the camera aspect ratio option has been removed. In previous versions, I could set the camera to a square view by adjusting the aspect ratio, but now it seems to default to a rectangular view.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve a square camera view with the new SDK? Are there any new methods or properties that need to be used?
Thanks in advance for your help!

it looks like they've removed multiple thing that only applied to android. I'd probably handle this by drawing a crop box over the camera view and cropping the returned image with in the app itself. you could look at getAvailablePictureSizesAsync() on android to see what options are avaiable but sounds like support is a per device thing

@danielRICADO getAvailablePictureSizesAsync is for make picture, we don't do this. We just do bar code scanning. Yes, crop box is a solution (bad), but it is strange camera still possible to see, even if we do hidden overflow.

you can pipe the blob returned out to a canvas and resize properly on the fly. If you're just scanning a barcode whats the image capture need for? Manually cropping isn't bad it's reliable between versions and is exactly what the vendor libraries do under the hood.

I see, but sounds like hard task for juniors.

its a common task, there are a ton of libraries and snippets that will get it done easily without the need for a deep dive, just search "image resize and crop javascript" and pick the tutorial, library, stack answer, gist or snippet that works for you the best. heres one right here at the top of the frirst page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479722/javascript-crop-and-scale-image-to-be-300-pixel

I even can't understand this, we don't do any photo, we just open camera and scan QR so we actually don't have any blob. we use just some kind of preview

then like the original suggestion just draw a mask over the camera display. Similar to
https://github.com/shahnawaz/react-native-barcode-mask

We found a solution. The solution is to migrate from native-base to gluestack (even migration lib).
